# Using WFS and Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, wfs

I'm quite new to Leaflet, and i would like to use this WFS,
https://wxs.ign.fr/agriculture/geoportail/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities,
to display interactive agricultural plots on a leaflet map.

I tried this:

```
var data_url ="https://wxs.ign.fr/agriculture/geoportail/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature";
    var params = '&Name=RPG.2020:parcelles_graphiques&outputFormat=application/json';
    var url =encodeURI(data_url+params) ;
    $.get(url, function(json){
        var obj = $.parseJSON(json);
        console.log(obj);
    });
```

it returns this in the console :

```
<ExceptionReport>
<script> try { Object.defineProperty(navigator, "globalPrivacyControl", { value: false, configurable: false, writable: false }); document.currentScript.parentElement.removeChild(document.currentScript); } catch(e) {}; </script>
<Exception exceptionCode="MissingParameter">Resource parameter not found</Exception>
</ExceptionReport>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is missing a version number, also for WFS 2 you need a `typenames` parameter, and for previous versions a `typename` with your GetFeature request.

The below request works for example:

> https://wxs.ign.fr/agriculture/geoportail/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&typeNames=RPG.2020:parcelles_graphiques&outputFormat=application/json&version=2.0.0&count=1

Gives:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"parcelles_graphiques.153165","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[2.49695832,47.13359959],[2.49911964,47.13497217],[2.50232895,47.1327338],[2.50048126,47.13167228],[2.49977537,47.13126967],[2.49916414,47.13091249],[2.49916414,47.13091249],[2.4991522,47.13090728],[2.49915218,47.13090728],[2.49613253,47.13270356],[2.49613253,47.13270357],[2.49648898,47.13295623],[2.49648898,47.13295623],[2.49688997,47.13318903],[2.49688998,47.13318903],[2.49688997,47.13318904],[2.49684257,47.13322098],[2.49684257,47.13322099],[2.49716883,47.13341892],[2.49716883,47.13341893],[2.49716883,47.13341893],[2.49695832,47.13359959]]]]},"geometry_name":"the_geom","properties":{"id_parcel":"9712268","surf_parc":10.8,"code_cultu":"LUZ","code_group":"16","culture_d1":"","culture_d2":"","bbox":[2.49613253,47.13090728,2.50232895,47.13497217]}}],"totalFeatures":9841300,"numberMatched":9841300,"numberReturned":1,"timeStamp":"2022-01-10T12:35:50.779Z","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326"}},"bbox":[47.13090728,2.49613253,47.13497217,2.50232895]}
```